# Django create dynamic model

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am building a web-page using python and Django and mysql and i have 5K tables that are identical in structure just the name is different

Example:

```
my_table_name_1
my_table_name_2
...
my_table_name_5000
```

How i can setup the model to have base template like "my_table_name_" and when i will call from the controller i want to pass the id and point to the right table

FYI: my app in the projects is called 'polls'

In my module.py i used ./manage.py inspectdb > models.py.
but what happens whenever i add a new table in the db..i have to do all of this manual everytime.
Thats why i want to make it dynamically..if i add a new table in the DB i want to be able to access it without using ./manage.py inspectdb.

this is my polls/views.py

```
 class AboutDetail(DetailView):
    model = Crawledtables
    pk_url_kwarg = 'table_id'
    template_name = 'polls/details.html'

    def get_object(self):
        if 'table_id' not in self.kwargs:
            return Crawledtables.objects.get(id=1)
        else:
            return Crawledtables.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['table_id'])

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'polls/base.html')


def tables(request):
    tables = Crawledtables.objects.order_by('id')
    table_list = {'list_tables': tables}
    return render(request, 'polls/tables.html', context=table_list)


class Details(ListView):
    model = Table1
    template_name = 'polls/details.html'
    context_object_name = 'list'
    paginate_by = 15
    queryset = Table1.objects.all()
```

CrawledTable is just a table with all the names of tables that i crawled in that DB.

polls/urls.py

```
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
        url(r'^tables/$', views.tables, name='tables'),
        url(r'^(?P<table_id>\d+)/details$', views.AboutDetail.as_view(), name='id_details'),
        url(r'^(?P<table_id>\d+)/details$', views.Details, name='details'),]
```

this is part of my tables.html
this is what tells it to get id number 4 or on whatever table id i m selecting
from the CrawledTables

```
<td><pre><a href="{% url 'polls:details' list.id%}">{{ list.name }}</a></pre></td>
```

So basically i got it to display 1 table...and now i m trying to display all tables dynamically. 
So Basically this is what happens now, if i select the 18th table  that i crawled and i want to get the details on it, it will still show me the the details of Table1. Because the 'class Details it is static'.
And now i want to change to if i select Table100 i want the inside details of Table100

UPDATED:
The 5000 tables was just a number. And when i said the structure is identical i meant The STRUCTURE IS THE SAME ( SAME COLUMNS) the data inside those tables IS COMPLETY DIFFERENT

Comment: Why do you have 5000 identical tables? That's unusual, to say the least.

Comment: The structure is the same but different details...and 5k was just a number...i dont have that many in 1 db

Comment: Different tables that differ only by a number in the name is a sure design smell. Either you want one single table with a "number" field or you want distinct databases. My 2 cents since I don't know about the concrete use case but I fail to see any situation where this design would be appropriate (and yes, I've seen this design in use in some (in)famous blogging software and it's a complete coding and maintainance nightmare).

Comment: this is not some "(in)famous" blogging thing...i will not give you in-depth info about it... i tried to give basic info. and it's simple...all tables with SAME STRUCTURE different data inside the table.